# How to generate url with Url->build in cakephp4 in template file?

Tags: php, url, version, cakephp-4.x

UrlBuilder not working in Cakephp 4

```
echo $this->Url->build(["plugin"=>"ContentManager","controller" => "pages","action" => "add"]);
```

Comment: Please note that "doesn't work" is not a proper problem description, please be more specific when describing problems, and explain what exactly happens, and what exactly you'd expect to happen instead - thanks!

Comment: Please share the output.